# Read a date from a .csv and put them in int

Tags: char, int, getline

my input is from a .csv and is as follows:

```
1135,"2015-07-19","2015-07-28",446
1130,"2015-12-14","2015-12-21",458
1105,"2015-04-01","2015-04-12",761
1125,"2015-01-01","2015-01-11",692
```

... etc

and i need to put 2015, 07 and 19 in a 3 different int variables ( int year,month,day) so i am able to calculate if a specific book is available for rent. I ve been using getline but sadly getline only work with char and i cant convert back my char into int... and without int i cant calculate if my book is available or not.

here was my code:

```
while(!fp2.eof())
{
    fp2.getline(copyNo,sizeof(copyNo),',');
    fp2.ignore(1);
    fp2.getline(dateOut.year,sizeof(dateOut.year),'-');
    fp2.getline(dateOut.month,sizeof(dateOut.month),'-');
    fp2.getline(dateOut.day,sizeof(dateOut.day),'"');
    fp2.ignore(2);
    fp2.getline(dateDue.year,sizeof(dateDue.year),'-');
    fp2.getline(dateDue.month,sizeof(dateDue.month),'-');
    fp2.getline(dateDue.day,sizeof(dateDue.day),'"');
    fp2.ignore(1);
    fp2.getline(borrowerNo,sizeof(borrowerNo));
}
```

is there a way i can change my getlines so the numbers of the dates are put in integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

made an input exactly as the .csv (YYYY-MM-DD) as string, changed my parse as 1 string and did as follow:

```
    while(!fp2.eof())
    {
        fp2.getline(copyNo,sizeof(copyNo),',');
        fp2.ignore(1);
        getline(fp2,dateOut,'"');
        fp2.ignore(2);
        getline(fp2,dateDue,'"');
        fp2.ignore(1);
        fp2.getline(borrowerNo,sizeof(borrowerNo));
    }

if(dateDue<today)
```